# Making a registration page with Heroku - NotFoundException errors

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to make a basic account registration page for a website using Heroku. I have installed PostGRESQL and created a table called users with all the proper columns. (I haven't used encryption yet since I'm just trying to get this working first.) Here is my PHP for the page:

```
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');
require('../includes/config.php');
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;
// Register the monolog logging service
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
'monolog.logfile' => 'php://stderr',
));
// Register the Twig templating engine
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));

/*checking database*/
    // if form was submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
         /**/
        //check that all three fields have been filled out
        if (empty($_POST["username"])||empty($_POST["password"])||empty($_POST["confirmation"]))         
        {     
             apologize("You need to complete the username, password, and confirmation fields.");
             exit;
        }       
        //check that password and confirmation are the same
        if ($_POST["password"] != $_POST["confirmation"])
        {
             apologize("Password and confirmation must match.");
             exit;
        }

        if (!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
        {
             apologize("Email address not valid. Try again.");        
             exit ; 
        }    


// Register the Postgres database add-on
$dbopts = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));
$app->register(new Herrera\Pdo\PdoServiceProvider(),
array   (
    'pdo.dsn' => 'pgsql:dbname='.ltrim($dbopts["path"],'/').';host='.$dbopts["host"],
    'pdo.port' => $dbopts["port"],
    'pdo.username' => $dbopts["user"],
    'pdo.password' => $dbopts["pass"]
    )
          );

$st = $app['pdo']->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, email, hash) VALUES ('. $_POST["username"] . ', ' . $_POST["email"]. ', '. $_POST["password"]. ')');
$st->execute();     

$app->get('/db/', function() use($app) {

$st = $app['pdo']->prepare('SELECT username FROM users');
$st->execute();
$names = array();
while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$app['monolog']->addDebug('Row ' . $row['name']);
$names[] = $row;
}
return $app['twig']->render('database.twig', array(
'names' => $names
));
});
$app->get('/twig/{name}', function($name) use($app) {
return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', array(
'name' => $name,
));
});
$app->run();
         //if the registration worked, log the user in
       if ($result !== false)
       {
            //if registration worked, remember that session ID
            $rows = query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id");
            $id = $rows[0]["id"];

            $_SESSION["id"] = $id; 
            redirect("../index.php");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        // else render form
        render("register_form.php", ["title" => "Register"]);
    }

?>
```

I am getting the following errors when I submit the page:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
2/2 NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 145: No route found for "POST /" (from "http://secret-ridge-6332.herokuapp.com/register.php")

```
in RouterListener.php line 145
at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))
at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher)) in EventDispatcher.php line 164
at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LogListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(MiddlewareListener), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in EventDispatcher.php line 53
at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in HttpKernel.php line 126
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 66
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 538
at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 515
at Application->run() in register.php line 72
```

1/2 ResourceNotFoundException in UrlMatcher.php line 96:

```
in UrlMatcher.php line 96
at UrlMatcher->match('/') in RedirectableUrlMatcher.php line 30
at RedirectableUrlMatcher->match('/') in LazyUrlMatcher.php line 51
at LazyUrlMatcher->match('/') in RouterListener.php line 127
at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))
at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher)) in EventDispatcher.php line 164
at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LogListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(MiddlewareListener), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in EventDispatcher.php line 53
at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in HttpKernel.php line 126
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 66
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 538
at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 515
at Application->run() in register.php line 72
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you're mixing your old way of programming with using Silex.

In general, you do `$app->get('/someroute', function(Request $request) { ... });` to respond to GET requests, with your code for that route "/someroute" inside the function, and `$app->post()` for POST requests. You do NOT use the `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc superglobals in any way but instead use the request object passed to these controller functions to access request data.

Please read some of the Silex tutorials out there and the main Silex manual to learn more.

I tried to clean up your app a little bit as an example, and gave it an index page, a login form route and POST handler, and a registration form route and POST handler. Please use prepared statements with bound parameters to protect yourself against SQL injection, and please do not store passwords in plain text in the database but `crypt()` them properly using BCrypt.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), [
    'monolog.logfile' => 'php://stderr',
]);
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));
$dbopts = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));
$app->register(new Herrera\Pdo\PdoServiceProvider(), array(
    'pdo.dsn' => sprintf('pgsql:dbname=%s;host=%s;port=%s', ltrim($dbopts["path"],'/'), $dbopts["host"], $dbopts["port"]);
    'pdo.username' => $dbopts["user"],
    'pdo.password' => $dbopts["pass"],
    'pdo.options' => array(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION),
));

$app->get('/', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    // your index code goes here, maybe render index.html.twig:
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig');
});

$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    // render login form here
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig');
});

$app->post('/login', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $email = $request->request->get('email');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
    // try to log in here
    $s = $app['pdo']->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    if($s->execute(array(':email' => $email))) {
        $u = $s->fetch();
        // compare crypted password to stored hash, constant time and all
        // the hash acts as the salt at the same time, clever stuff
        if(!password_verify($password, $u['password'])) {
            // password wrong
        } else {
            // login okay
        }
    } else {
        // no such user
    }
});

$app->get('/register', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    // render registration form here
    return $app['twig']->render('register.html.twig');
});

$app->post('/register', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $email = $request->request->get('email');
    // hash password using bcrypt (safe "2y" algorithm, cost factor 10, random salt)
    $password = password_hash($request->request->get('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $s = $app['pdo']->prepare('INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES(:email, :password)');
    $s->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':password' => $password));
    // success page unless there is an exception
});
```

I didn't test this, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I am going to take some time to go through this today and definitely the Silex manuals.